# Json encoded array Split Using php

Tags: php, arrays, json, api

I'm actually new to the Api world, i'm working on an Api that fetches and sends back data using a Curl Request. On Fetch the information below is passed

```
{"posts":{"userinfo":{"fullname":"Precious Tom","user_name":"Kendrick","email":"tomprezine@gmail.com","gender":"Male","country":"Nigeria","city":"Port Harcourt","state":"Rivers","year":"1997","month":"9","day":"6"}}}
```

content type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

http code: 200

Splitting the Array seem to be my Problem, I'm sorry if this question hs been asked before, but please, i need your help.
Thanks.

For More Info, Here is my Curl Request

```
<?php
session_start();
# data to be sent
$data = array(
'public_key' => 'pk_test_3gc9ffb0hccggf5f3b4e258da848343dff4ae900',
'app_name' => 'Circlepanda',
'app_id' => '2147483647'
);
$curl = curl_init();
# you can also set the url you wanna communicate with by setting
# $curl = curl_init('http://localhost/circlepanda');
  # We post Data
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
# Set the url path we want to call
 curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:8888/circlepanda/api/userinfo');
# Make it so the data coming back is put into a string
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  # You can also bunch the above commands into an array if you choose using: curl_setopt_array
# Send the request
$result = curl_exec($curl);
# Get some cURL session information back
$info = curl_getinfo($curl);
echo '<br> content type: ' . $info['content_type'] . '<br>';echo 'http code: ' . $info['http_code'] . '<br>';
# Free up the resources $curl is using
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

I'll be passing a Variable not a direct Array.
Tried Direct arrays your code worked fine, burr on passing a variable, it stopped working...

Comment: so what is the problem

Comment: Show any code you have been tried so far

Comment: print_r(json_decode('{"posts":{"userinfo":{"fullname":"Precious Tom","user_name":"Kendrick","email":"tomprezine@gmail.com","gender":"Male","country":"Nigeria","city":"Port Harcourt","state":"Rivers","year":"1997","month":"9","day":"6"}}}',true));

Answer (score 1):

```
$city_names = json_decode('{"posts":{"userinfo":{"fullname":"Precious Tom","user_name":"Kendrick","email":"tomprezine@gmail.com","gender":"Male","country":"Nigeria","city":"Port Harcourt","state":"Rivers","year":"1997","month":"9","day":"6"}}}', true);

print_r($city_names);
```

ans

```
Array
(
    [posts] => Array
        (
            [userinfo] => Array
                (
                    [fullname] => Precious Tom
                    [user_name] => Kendrick
                    [email] => tomprezine@gmail.com
                    [gender] => Male
                    [country] => Nigeria
                    [city] => Port Harcourt
                    [state] => Rivers
                    [year] => 1997
                    [month] => 9
                    [day] => 6
                )

        )

)

$city_names = json_decode($json, true);
print $arr['posts']['userinfo']['fullname'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You've 2 options:

1 - Convert `json` to an `object` using:

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
print $obj->posts->userinfo->fullname;
```

2 - convert `json` to an `array` using:

```
$arr = json_decode($json, true);
print $arr['posts']['userinfo']['fullname'];
```

---

Learn more about [`json_decode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)